# Find value from the dataview using column name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I am trying to find value from dataview using column name. My dataset shows value but my if condition  returns false. I am working in asp.net using c#.

I have tried with different code. I am trying to get value like this

```
dv[0].DataView.Table.Columns[0].ToString().Contains("52")
   //RETURN FALSE

OR

dv[0].Equals("52")
   // //RETURN FALSE
```

OR

```
dv[0].Find("52")
   // //RETURN FALSE
```

Following is my dataset
[image]

Comment: are you looking for somthing like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yth8t382%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?

Answer (score 2):

If "GBA_Nbr_GBAccount" column is a string type, it may contains spaces.
You should trim text before comparing. Try this

```
dv[0]["GBA_Nbr_GBAccount"].ToString().Trim().Equals("52");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Linq` to query the datatable or the dataview. For example, assuming your column is of type string:

```
var condition = yourDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                             .Any(r => r.Field<string>("GBA_Nbr_GBAccount") == "52");

var condition = yourDataView.Cast<DataRowView>()
                            .Any(rv => rv.Row.Field<string>("GBA_Nbr_GBAccount") == "52");
```

If the column was an integer, just change the `Field<string>` to `Field<int>` and compare against an integer, not a string

```
var condition = yourDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                             .Any(r => r.Field<int>("GBA_Nbr_GBAccount") == 52);

var condition = yourDataView.Cast<DataRowView>()
                            .Any(rv => rv.Row.Field<int>("GBA_Nbr_GBAccount") == 52);
```

Example application using string column:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    dataset.Tables.Add(new DataTable("table1"));
    dataset.Tables[0].Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", typeof(string)));
    dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Add("10");
    dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Add("52");

    DataTable table = dataset.Tables[0];
    DataView view = table.DefaultView;

    var condition1 = table.AsEnumerable().Any(r => r.Field<string>("Value") == "52");

    var condition2 = view.Cast<DataRowView>().Any(rv => rv.Row.Field<string>("Value") == "52");

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Result querying datatable: '{0}'. Result using dataview:'{1}'", condition1, condition2));
     Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If you are really using a string for the column, check for white spaces and apply a trim if needed.

Answer (score 1):

One way to check for the existence of a specific column in a dataview would be like the following:

```
if (dv.Table.Columns["Name"] != null)
{
//Name column exists. Add Logic here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the DataViewManager object instead
it has a DataSet property associated with it and the dataset has all the normal dataset features. So, you can traverse the dataset.tables[index] object...

Hope it helps

**Example**: `dv.DataViewManager.DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][1]`

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: What if I want the last column of the first row?

Comment: if you want to get the column by column name then use this 

<code>
var value = dv.DataViewManager.DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ColumnName"];
</code>
OR 
if you want to get the last column of the first row then use this:
<code>
int maxColumns = dv.DataViewManager.DataSet.Tables[0].Columns.Count;

var value = dv.DataViewManager.DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][maxColumns - 1];
</code>

Hope it is in line of what you were asking...
Thanks,

Comment: As mentioned in the documentation, DataViews may be created without a DataViewManager, and in that case DataViewManager is null.

Answer (score 0):

```
int rowIndex = dv.Find("52");

if (rowIndex == -1) {
    Console.WriteLine("No match found.");
} 
else {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", 
    dv(rowIndex)("GBA_Nbr_GBAccount").ToString(), 
    dv(rowIndex)("GBA_Nam_GBAccount").ToString());
}
```

I think that may be the solution to your problem, or at the very least point you in the right direction.

Comment: Note that the Find method search only by the sort key value
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.find?view=netframework-4.7.2